# How can i specify the code to read through all <Module> that are in only the <Keystage3> node

Tags: c#, xml, element, xmlnode

Here is the current code I have which outputs all tags with the name Module however I want to specify it to read through only the `<keystage3>` and so read all modules which are within this tag.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("Data.xml");
            var subjects = from subject in root.Descendants()
                          where subject.Name.LocalName.Contains("Subject")
                          select new
                          {
                              subname = subject.Element("subjectName").Value,
                              subid = subject.Element("subjectId").Value,
                              subvalue = subject.Element("subjectvalue").Value
                          };

            foreach (var subject in subjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(subject); 
                //you can use subject like this:
                string subName = subject.subname;
                string subID = subject.subid;
                string subValue = subject.subvalue;
                TextBox[] info = new TextBox[6];



                textBox1.AppendText("Subject Name :  " + subName + "  Subject Id :  " + subID + "  Subject Value :  " + subValue + " " );
            }
```

my xml file contains :

```
<PersonDetails>
  <PersonTitle>Teacher</PersonTitle>
  <Keystage3>
    <Subject>
      <subjectName>maths</subjectName>
      <subjectId>qq1</subjectId>
      <subjectvalue>20</subjectvalue>
      <subjectscore />
    </Subject>
    <Subject>
      <subjectName>science</subjectName>
      <subjectId>sla1s</subjectId>
      <subjectvalue>25</subjectvalue>
      <subjectscore />
    </Subject>
  </Keystage3>
 <Keystage4>
  <Subject>
      <subjectName>ICT</subjectName>
      <subjectId>a1</subjectId>
      <subjectvalue>10</subjectvalue>
      <subjectscore />
  </Subject>
 </Keystage4>
</PersonDetails>
```

So my question is How can i specify the code to read through all `<Module>` that are in only the `<Keystage3>` as the current code gives me all the `<Module>` for the entire xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pre-filter the descendants by "keystage3" and then filter down like you already did:

```
    internal class Program
    {
        private static string txt = @"
<PersonDetails><PersonTitle>Teacher</PersonTitle><Keystage3><Subject>
<subjectName>maths</subjectName><subjectId>qq1</subjectId><subjectvalue>20</subjectvalue>
<subjectscore /></Subject><Subject><subjectName>science</subjectName>
<subjectId>sla1s</subjectId><subjectvalue>25</subjectvalue><subjectscore />
</Subject></Keystage3><Keystage4><Subject><subjectName>ICT</subjectName>
<subjectId>a1</subjectId><subjectvalue>10</subjectvalue><subjectscore />
</Subject></Keystage4></PersonDetails>";

        static void Main()
        {
            XElement root = XElement.Parse(txt); // Load -> Parse
            var subjects = from stage in root.Descendants()
                           where stage.Name.LocalName == "Keystage3"
                           from subject in stage.Descendants()
                           where subject.Name.LocalName.Contains("Subject")
                           select new
                           {
                               subname = subject.Element("subjectName").Value,
                               subid = subject.Element("subjectId").Value,
                               subvalue = subject.Element("subjectvalue").Value
                           };

            foreach (var subject in subjects) 
                Console.WriteLine(subject); 

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
{ subname = maths, subid = qq1, subvalue = 20 }
{ subname = science, subid = sla1s, subvalue = 25 }
```

Comment: I have another question regarding my code which is how can i iterate depending on how many <subject> nodes there are and create dynamic labels depending on the number of <subject> nodes